# Javascript / jQuery : Select class name that contains word

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, variables, select

How can I do this:

I have object that has multiple classes. My goal is to get class name that has string(e.g. 'toaster') in it (or starting with that string) and put it in variable.Note that I know only the beggining of class name and I need to get whole.

e.g. `<div class="writer quite-good toaster-maker"></div>`

I have this div as my jQuery object, I only need to put class name `toaster-maker` in variable `className`;

Again I don't need to select object! I only need to put class name in variable.

Comment: Will that class always be written as the last one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, assuming you already have a jQuery object with that div, you could get the value of the `class` attribute, split the string into the class names, iterate over them and see which one contains `toaster`:

```
var className = '';
$.each($element.attr('class').split(/\s+/), function(i, name) {
    if (name.indexOf('toaster') > -1) { // or name.indexOf('toaster') === 0
        className = name;
        return false;
    }
});
```

jQuery doesn't provide an specific function for that.

If you have multiple elements for which you want to extract the class names, you can use `.map`:

```
var classNames = $elements.map(function() {
    $.each(this.className.split(/\s+/), function(i, name) {
        if (name.indexOf('toaster') > -1) { // or name.indexOf('toaster') === 0
            return name;
        }
    });
}).get();
```

`classNames` will then be an array of class names.

In browser which support [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList), you could also use `$.each(this.classList, ...)` instead of `$.each(this.className.split(/\s+/), ...)`.

Comment: `function(name)` should be `function(key, name)`. Otherwise you'll use the index as the string

Comment: Thanks! Another victim of jQuery's confusing callback parameter order ;)

Answer (score 8):

A regular expression seems to be more efficient here:

```
classNames = div.attr("class").match(/[\w-]*toaster[\w-]*/g)
```

returns all class names that contain "toaster" (or an empty array if there are none).

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
var names = $('[class*=toaster]').attr('class').split(' ');
var className;
$.each(names, function(){
if (this.toLowerCase().indexOf("toaster") >= 0)
    className = this;
    })
console.log(className);
```

fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SzgWU/). You can also have className as an array and push the matched class names to it.